# Jenkins pipeline - How to make a stage work for both Windows and Linux

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am developing a declarative pipeline on Jenkins and one of the requisites is that it must work for both Windows and Linux.

Right now, to achieve this I am making use of two stages, one for Linux environment and the other one for Windows environment, as it is possible to see in the code below

```
stage('Integration Tests on Windows') {
   when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
      steps 
      {
         dir('') 
         {
            bat 'gradlew.bat integrationTest'
            junit '**/build/test-results/integrationTest/*.xml'
         }
       }
}

stage('Integration Tests on LINUX') {
   when { expression { env.OS == 'UNIX' }}
      steps 
      {
         dir('') 
         {
            sh 'gradlew integrationTest'
            junit '**/build/test-results/integrationTest/*.xml'
         }
       }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this while keeping the pipeline declarative?

Comment: That's the best you can do just with Declarative syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are using git. However our preferred way to do this is by using the `sh` step on both Linux and Windows:

We do this by using the bash/sh which comes with Windows git. You just need to ensure that it (`sh`) is in the path (if e.g. you do a manual install git will even ask you to add its command line tools to the path). For the Jenkins nodes you may want to add this to your Jenkins node configuration.

One alternative we use is a wrapper function which you may specify somewhere in your Jenkinsfile or in a Pipeline library. It may look something like this:

```
def executeCmd(def args) {
    if (isUnix()) {
        sh args 
    } else {
        bat args
    }
}
```

Please note that this obviously can only handle cases where the arguments would be 100% identical on Windows and Linux.

Therefore I would recommend to use `sh` on Windows and Linux.

Or if you prefer you may want to Powershell on Linux and use the `pwsh` step instead.